# What could be causing this JavaScript error?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm modifying an ASP.NET webform that loads a user control.  In the user control there is JavaScript that is generating an error.  The error is:

> JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property
>   'GetFirstItineraryObjects' is null or undefined, not a Function object

This is a call in a list of function calls containing:

```
GetFirstItineraryObjects();
```

And yes, when I examine the page source when it renders (after blowing past the JS error), this function is indeed there.  I did wonder if the one line in this function that I modified might be causing the problem, so I commented it out. But the error still occurs.

What can cause a JavaScript runtime error of this nature?

I don't think this will help much, but here's the code which adds the JavaScript.  Note that the entire page is rendered and sent to the browser before the browser can possibly execute any JavaScript in the page (this is for @Arwind).

```
clientScriptKey = "SetOriginalMileageObjectValues";
clientScriptText = string.Empty;

if (!clientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(clientScriptType, clientScriptKey))
{
    clientScriptText = "function GetFirstItineraryObjects()" + Environment.NewLine;
    clientScriptText += "            {" + Environment.NewLine;
    // a bunch of code
    clientScriptText += "            }" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
    clientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(clientScriptType, clientScriptKey, clientScriptText, true);
}

clientScriptKey = "CreateMileageDataOldValues";
clientScriptText = string.Empty;

if (!clientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(clientScriptType, clientScriptKey))
{
    clientScriptText = "GetFirstItineraryObjects();" + Environment.NewLine;
    clientScriptText += "GetFromLocationOldValues();" + Environment.NewLine;
    clientScriptText += "GetToLocationOldValues();" + Environment.NewLine;
    clientScriptText += "GetStartDateOldValues();" + Environment.NewLine;
    clientScript.RegisterStartupScript(clientScriptType, clientScriptKey, clientScriptText, true);
}
```

Upon further examination, all four of those function calls (not just GetFirstItineraryObjects) throw the same JavaScript error, AND the functions do exist at runtime.

Comment: Some code would be useful to pin point the cause of error.

Comment: Some code added, @SudhansuChoudhary

Answer (score 0):

[**comment**(as I do not have the privilege to comment)]:- Please ensure the definition of GetFirstItineraryObjects() function is loading first before you calling it in your page.

Comment: *And yes, when I examine the page source when it renders (after blowing past the JS error), this function is indeed there*, the OP has mentioned that the function defn is there. And are you sure this answer qualifies as an answer? it's more of a comment.

Comment: it looks like I could not post a comment yet?

Comment: Ahh, ok :) well just edit the answer and provide the same info, that would be self explainatory.

Comment: Done. Edit as a comment.

Comment: As I indicate in the question (as amended), ASP.NET renders the entire page before sending to the browser, so both function and function call are loaded when it gets called.  That's how ASP.NET works.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly missing `<script></script>` tags around javascript parts, [here's example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy(v=vs.110).aspx).